# text data compression using Huffman encoding

Tags: c, encoding, structure, huffman-code

I'm starting a new project,  a text data arhivator, that will use [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

What structure is better to use  in implementation of such an algorithm?

My approach is to create a simply linked list that will contain binary trees in each node. In order to build the Huffman-tree.

Is there a better way?

Comment: A structure for what?

Comment: Linked list combined with a binary trees might be overkill for a Huffman codec. You haven't described much about what you hope to achieve with this project. But a Huffman tree can usually be simply represented using a static array that contains twice as much space as there are possible elements. E.g., if you are encoding 8-bit bytes, since there are 256 possible elements, the Huffman tree can be an array of 512 items. There are even better approaches than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about generating the Huffman code from the symbol frequencies (your question is not clear), then the data structure can be implicit in the storage of the tree.  In fact, the calculation can be done in place, over the frequencies.  See [In-Place Calculation of Minimum-Redundancy Codes](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/jyrki/Paper/WADS95.pdf).